# Can't set ManyToOne OneToMany for entities, have double persistance

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, many-to-one

```
@Entity
public class Room {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Room", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<SponsorStart> sponsorsStart = new ArrayList<>();
//getters setters
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sponsors_start")
public class SponsorStart {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String username;
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "room_id")
    private Room Room;
```

```
@Repository
public interface RoomRepository extends CrudRepository<Room, Long> {

}

From RoomServiceImpl save:
  @Override
    public Room saveRoom(Room Room) {
        return roomRepository.save(Room);
    }
```

What my sequence of acts?

```
1. List<SponsorStart> sponsorStarts = new ArrayList<>();
2. Room room = new Room();
3. giveRoom.setSponsorsStart(sponsorStarts); //set list of sponsors form p.1
4. giveRoomService.saveRoom(room); //save room
```

And sponsors_start db is empty.
I tried save first each sposorStart from list but they saved with null in room_id column.
Sorry i know that should be simple but in my case i do something wrong.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should move `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` on the `@OneToMany` side of your association:

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "Room", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<SponsorStart> sponsorsStart = new ArrayList<>();
```

2. You should sync both side of bidirectional association:

```java
List<SponsorStart> sponsorStarts = new ArrayList<>();
SponsorStart sponsorStart1 = new SponsorStart();
sponsorStarts.add(sponsorStart1);
// ...

Room room = new Room();

// sync both side of the association
sponsorStart1.setRoom(room);
room.setSponsorsStart(sponsorStarts); //set list of sponsors form p.1
room.saveRoom(room); //save room
```

See also [this part](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional) of the hibernate documentation.

Comment: I told that is simple) I should set into each other entities then save it! Thanks

Comment: Maybe it will be more elegant to add `addSponsorStart()` and `removeSponsorStart()` utility methods that synchronize both ends whenever a child element is added or removed (see example in the referred part of the documentation).